# Prove the following fact about a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

Consider the following recursive relation: 
$$T(1)=1$$
$$T(n)=2T\left(\left\lfloor \frac n 2\right\rfloor\right)\text{ for }n\geq 2$$
It is required to show that
$$T(n)=2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$$
I tried to solve this problem by considering two cases $n=2^b$, where $b\geq 1$ and $n=a\cdot 2^b$, where $a$ is an odd number. In the first case observe that $$T(2^b)=2\cdot T(2^{b-1})$$
$$=2^2\cdot T(2^{b-2})$$
$$...$$
$$T(2^b)=2^b$$
Also observe that 
$$2^{\lfloor \log_2 2^b\rfloor}=2^b$$ so we are done for case 1. I am facing difficulty in proving for case 2, when $n=a\cdot 2^b$. Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest separating the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I tried doing that earlier but couldn't proceed with much success, could you please elaborate this argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b$ is the largest integer such that $2^b$ divides $n$ with remainder $\geq 0$ then $$b=\lfloor{\log_2n\rfloor}.$$ Also $$\left\lfloor\frac 1 2\left\lfloor \frac n 2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac {n} {2^2}\right\rfloor$$ for integer $n$. 
So $$T(n)=2T\left(\left\lfloor \frac n 2\right\rfloor\right)=2^2T\left(\left\lfloor \frac {n} {2^2}\right\rfloor\right)=\cdots=2^bT(1)=2^b$$

Answer (score 3):

Take the binary logarithm of the recurrence:
$$T'(1)=0\qquad T'(n)=1+T'(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$$
The function $n\mapsto\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is a right shift by one bit. It follows that if $n$ has $k+1=\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor+1$ bits, $k$ applications of the function are required to reach 1. Therefore $T'(n)=\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor$ and $T(n)=2^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}$.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean by right shift a bit...The terminology is new.

Comment: @ShreyAryan A right shift by one bit means "divide by two and delete the bit  that is now after the radix point". This, together with the left shift, is very common in practical computing. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift).